# Histogram not working on Python; Jupyter; Stuck on loading

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm learning pandas now and I'm trying to construct a simply histogram plot. However, whenever I execute the command it just stalls the  program completely. I could leave it for hours (as I did) and it still stuck on * for  jupyter.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os 
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#!{sys.executable} -m pip install seaborn
import seaborn
%pylab inline
%matplotlib inline

os.chdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop')
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data.head()
```

[image]

```
data.shape()
```

Output: (7362,6)

```
data.columns
hist(data.Storage)
#Tried this command first
```

Then it never loaded and the kernel was frozen- not running any command 
    after stuck on *

```
#So I tried this command
plt.hist(data.Storage)
plt.ylabel('No of times')
plt.show()
```

Any ideas what could be happpening? It's not a massive dataset by any means (7k observations) so I'm unsure what it is. Although, when I cut this dataset to only 100 observations it worked. I also tried a different dataset with 500K observations and it took a while but eventually loaded. Any recommendations?

Comment: Is there invalid data (like an *) in the original dataset, somewhere between row 101 and 7k?

Comment: Did you try doing `data.Storage.hist()`?

Comment: Yes thank you!! I found some n.a.'s that mustve thrown it off.